# Use a filesystem directory instead of pypi behind a corporate firewall?

Tags: python, windows, setuptools

I am working on a product with a large number of python dependencies within a corporation that does not permit servers to contact external machines. Any attempt to circumvent this rule would be judged harshly.

The application is deployed via a batch-script (it's 32 bit windows) into a virtualenv. This batch script (ideally) should do nothing more than

```
# Precondition: Source code has been checked-out into myprog/src
cd myprog/src
setup.py install # <-- fails because of dependencies
myprog.exe
```

The problem comes with managing the dependencies - since it's impossible for the server to connect to the outside world my only solution is to have the script easy_install each of the dependencies before the setup starts, something like this:

```
cd myproc/deps/windows32
easy_install foo-1.2.3.egg
easy_install bar-2.3.4.egg
easy_install baz-3.4.5.egg <-- works but is annoying/wrong
cd ../../myprog/src
setup.py install
myprog.exe
```

What I'd like to do is make it so that the setup.py script knows where to fetch it's dependencies from. Ideally this should be set as a command-line argument or environment variable, that way I'm not going to hard-code the location of the dependencies into the project.

Ideally I'd like all of the eggs to be part of a 'distributions' directory: This can be on a network drive, shared on a web-server or possibly even be deployed to a local folder on each of the servers.

Can this be done?

Comment: You can try setting up your own partial mirror; the [PyPI source code](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi) is available. I'm not posting this as an answer because I've never actually tried.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is these options to `pip`: [--no-index](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html#no-index) and [--find-links](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html#find-links):

```
--no-index
--find-links /my/local/archives
--find-links http://some.archives.com/archives
```

Docs are [here](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#requirements-file-format).

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted: I'm not running the pip utility, i'm running setup.py since the main application is deployed as source. Any suggestions?

Comment: But if your app has `setup.py` script, it can be installed via `pip install --ignore-installed .` instead of `setup.py install`. Can you check this? If that works, `pip` will honor all listed dependencies of your app. Or alternatively, you can create file `requirements.txt`, put there all your requirements and run `pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links <path to dir with eggs>` before installing your app.